# How to enableQueryLog Database Laravel after app start.

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5

I want get Query in controller laravel but i must `DB::enableQueryLog()` in function i using `DB::getQueryLog()` . I want `DB::enableQueryLog()` when app start. To be `DB::getQueryLog()` without `DB::enableQueryLog()` in controller.

Please help! Thank so much

Answer (score 1):

You can serve all queries through `\DB::listen`. For example in one of your ServiceProvider you can use the following code to register a listener to log all your queries into the file:

```
if (app()->environment() == 'local') {
    \DB::listen(function ($event) {
        app('<your custom logger>')->debug(\Request::getPathInfo() . '[' . $event->time . '] ' . $event->sql, $event->bindings);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it is not i want . I want get query raw and save in database